# Alexa AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME Slot Validation

Tags: validation, alexa-skills-kit, slot

I am currently building an Alexa application that analyzes a user's name. I currently have a slot (called name) that uses the built in AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME slot type. I want to validate the name by comparing it against amazon's list of US_FIRST_NAMES, instead of having to download a list of names somewhere and comparing the user's name against the list. Is there any way to do this through the Amazon Developer Console?

Note: In Amazon's docs (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/validate-slot-values.html) I have read that there are ways to validate built in slots. However, on the development console, the validation tab for my name slot only allows me to accept or reject the user's input from a list of names that I have provided, not Amazon's built US_FIRST_NAME list. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

In the Alexa console, you have three options:

You can define a custom list of values to accept or reject, or you can choose to accept only the slot type's values and synonyms.

If you see the option to accept the slot type's values and synonyms, I imagine this will do what you are looking for. 
If for some reason it doesn't give you that option, then you could actually create a custom slot type and copy and paste the entire list of US names from Amazon into the proper place in your JSON file, though this would make for quite a large file. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it only gives me the option to accept or reject certain values. I thought about uploading the entire list of names in a CSV file but it seems hacky and kind to me defeats the purpose to having a built in slot for AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAMES in the first place. I hope they build in automatic validation soon!

Comment: I hear you. Have you thought about doing it from the Lambda side? I'm not sure if Amazon has their list of names available online, but you could program in some logic to see if the name is in their list of names via a GET request if that info is publicly available.

Comment: I thought about doing it serverside, but it seemed hacky lol. Its all good, the application i was making was just for a coding challenge. I mentioned in the notes that I would have done it serverside if it was production. Thanks for your help man

Comment: No problem. VUI is still an infant relative to GUI, so we get to help to figure all this stuff out. Maybe suggest it to Amazon! Cheers.